# How to solve the undefine method and expand path error in Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I ran the command line: `$ bundle exec rackup --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000`

But got this error:

```
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:272:in `search_up': undefined method `untaint' for "E:/下载/hw-sinatra-saas-wordguesser-master/app":String (NoMethodError)

      current  = File.expand_path(SharedHelpers.pwd).untaint
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:259:in `find_file'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:251:in `find_gemfile'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:27:in `root'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:234:in `root'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:246:in `app_config_path'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:273:in `settings'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/feature_flag.rb:21:in `block in settings_method'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:97:in `<class:CLI>'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:7:in `<module:Bundler>'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
        from <internal:D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/Ruby32-x64/bin/bundle:32:in `load'        from D:/Ruby32-x64/bin/bundle:32:in `<main>'
```

Why does the error occur? Why can't I open my app?

I've tried to use the command line `bundle exec rackup --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000`instead, but also failed. I excepted some useful idea and solution towards the question.

Comment: you need to update `bundler`

Comment: `Kernel#untaint` (and friends) were removed in 3.2 (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16131#note-15) you will need to update `bundler` (current version is 2.5.7)